# Could not able to get the access token from Reddit API through Scala

Tags: scala, web-applications, access-token, reddit

I have went through the Reddit API doc. I have to make a web app (not script)
[Screen shot from the github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxpGA.png) 
https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2

As far now, i am able to get the authorization  code , but i am not sure how to how to get the access token. 
Actually , it is written that i don't have to send the grant code and redirect URI parameter in post not in URL, I am not sure what does that mean.
Attaching screen shot.